# How do I make this box in LaTeX?

Tags: tikz-pgf

As the the title suggests I do not know how to make a box like this and I need the exact one for my chemistry notes. Any help would be very appreciated as I am new to LaTeX.

[image]

Some context: this picture is from a document by a lecturer

https://castel.dev/notes

He has linked his GitHub code as well but it says there `\begin{eq}` which does not explain how he made his boxes look like this.

Comment: Welcome! Why don't you ask your lecturer? There isn't much point in giving you code with undefined commands unless defining them is the point of some assignment, which presumably isn't the case here. If you still need help, post code for a minimal document people can compile which illustrates where you're having trouble.

Comment: And why do you need the 'exact same one' for *your* notes?

Comment: You could take a look at the package `tcolorbox` (https://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox). This is a package where your can easily customize how such boxes with titles and (partial) frames look like.

Comment: You can find the exact definition of the "eg" environment in the file "preamble.tex" on GitHub. It's using the thmtools and mdframed packages. As mentioned by BanDoP, you could also take a look at the fantastic tcolorbox package to create a box like this one.

Comment: Questions on this site should be selfcontained, that is, they should not link to other sites as links can deteriorate over time. Also, questions should show some efforts by the original poster so that it makes clear where their problems are exactly.

Answer (score 6):

As everybody said in the comments, the code was defined in the `preamble.tex` file on github. I am not sure if showing some of the code here will help you to learning or not. However, I decided to do it. Here is a example, using exact same definition from github (only contain the example, proof and definition).

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\mdfsetup{skipabove=1em,skipbelow=0em}

\declaretheoremstyle[
    headfont=\bfseries\sffamily\color{ForestGreen!70!black}, bodyfont=\normalfont,
    mdframed={
        linewidth=2pt,
        rightline=false, topline=false, bottomline=false,
        linecolor=ForestGreen, backgroundcolor=ForestGreen!5,
    }
]{thmgreenbox}

\declaretheoremstyle[
    headfont=\bfseries\sffamily\color{NavyBlue!70!black}, bodyfont=\normalfont,
    mdframed={
        linewidth=2pt,
        rightline=false, topline=false, bottomline=false,
        linecolor=NavyBlue, backgroundcolor=NavyBlue!5,
    }
]{thmbluebox}

\declaretheoremstyle[
    headfont=\bfseries\sffamily\color{NavyBlue!70!black}, bodyfont=\normalfont,
    numbered=no,
    mdframed={
        linewidth=2pt,
        rightline=false, topline=false, bottomline=false,
        linecolor=NavyBlue, backgroundcolor=NavyBlue!1,
    },
]{thmexplanationbox}

\declaretheorem[style=thmgreenbox, name=Definition]{definition}
\declaretheorem[style=thmbluebox, numbered=no, name=Example]{eg}
\declaretheorem[style=thmexplanationbox, name=Proof]{tmpexplanation}
\newenvironment{explanation}[1][]{\vspace{-10pt}\begin{tmpexplanation}}{\end{tmpexplanation}}

\begin{document}
\begin{eg}
    Suppose we have a functor.
    If $G_X \not\cong G_Y$, then  $X$ and  $Y$ are not homeomorphic.
    If `shadows' are different, then objects themselves are different too.
\end{eg}
\begin{explanation}
    Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are homeomorphic.
    Then $\exists f: X \to  Y$ and $g: Y \to  X$, maps (maps are always continuous in this course), such that $g  \circ f = 1_X$ and $f \circ g = 1_Y$.
    Then $f_*: G_X \to G_Y$ and $g_*: G_Y \to  G_X$ such that $(g \circ f)_* = (1_X)_*$ and  $(f \circ g)_* = (1_Y)_*$. Using the rules discussed previously, we get
    \[
    g_*  \circ f_* = 1_{G_X} \quad f_*  \circ  g_* = 1_{G_Y}
    ,\] 
    which means that $f_* : G_X \to  G_Y$ is an isomorphism.
\end{explanation}
\begin{definition}[Homotopy]
    Let $f,g:X\to Y$ be maps (so continuous). Then a homotopy between $f$ and $g$ is a continuous map $H: X\times I \to Y$ such that
    \begin{itemize}
        \item $H(x, 0) = f(x)$, $H(x, 1) = g(x)$ 
        \item For all $t \in I$, define $f_t: X \to  Y: x \mapsto  H(x, t)$
    \end{itemize}
    We say that $f$ is homotopic with $g$, we write $f \simeq g$.
    If $g$ is a constant map, we say that $f$ is null homotopic.
\end{definition}
\end{document}
```

[image]